# How to marshal and unmarshal or convert objects while avoiding type in golang

Tags: dataframe, go, google-sheets-api

I'm working on code to integrate Google Sheets with a dataframe sdk: https://github.com/kniren/gota.  This code causes a panic at   "df := dataframe.LoadRecords(values)" everytime. When I use a debugger it shows a panic.  Everything in the watcher shows values in my [][]string exactly as expected. If there is a better way to convert sheets cells into an [][]string, please comment.

```
package main

import (
    "bitbucket.org/gosheets"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    sheetdata := gosheets.Setup()
    // row1 is column names
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(sheetdata.Values))
    values := [][]string{}
    //sheetdata.Values.(*sheets.ValueRange)
    fmt.Sprintln(sheetdata.Values)
    for _, row := range sheetdata.Values.Values {
        sr := []string{}
        for i, cell := range row {
            //capping columns at 5 for starters
            if i >= 5 {
                break
            }
            sr = append(sr, fmt.Sprint(cell))
        }
        fmt.Sprintln(row)
        values = append(values, sr)
        //values = append(values, fmt.Sprintln(row))
    }
    //opts := dataframe.LoadOption{detectTypes: false}
    df := dataframe.LoadRecords(values)

    //df := dataframe.ReadCSV(sheetdata.Values)
    //fmt.Println(sheetdata.Values)
    fmt.Println(df.Names())

}
```

Comment: What is the panic, including the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide a runnable example, as it makes it easier to debug. This looks like it uses private code, but you should be able to reproduce without using your gosheets lib, with test input.

So trying this for example as sheetdata produces a panic:

```
sheetdata := [][]string{{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hJXBlO_40O

so if your error is this:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe.LoadRecords(0xc420058060, 0x2, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe/dataframe.go:693 +0xc53
```

Your probably have data which has header fields longer than following rows (assuming it is looking at csv data). This assumption is baked in [here](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/kniren/gota@531ec7b7d82e2a7b7355b63011197a29d401aba6/-/blob/dataframe/dataframe.go#L710), LoadRecords should really check and return an error not panic.